# On the sine of a two by two matrix with integer entries

Tags: matrices, number-theory, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

Let $A \in M(2,\mathbb Z)$ ; Let

$\sin A :=\sum _{n=0}^\infty \dfrac {(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}A^{2n+1}$ (This series is known to converge absolutely in the Banach space $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^2)$ under Operator norm ) .

If $\sin A \in M(2,\mathbb Z)$ , then is it true that $A^2=O$ ?

Comment: The hard way would be to look at the Jordan normal form $A = P J P^{-1}, \sin(A) = P \sin(J) P^{-1}$

Answer (score 5):

**Note** - Haven't received that many downvotes for a single answer for a while.

I suspect people downvote this because it uses something too advanced for
a problem that looks trivial. In fact, if the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ 
of $A$ are both real (say $A$ is real symmetric), then this problem is indeed trivial. This is because when $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are real,
$$|\det\sin(A)| = |\sin(\lambda_1)\sin(\lambda_2)| \le 1 \quad\text{ and }\quad |{\rm tr} \sin(A)| = |\sin(\lambda_1) + \sin(\lambda_2)| \le 2$$
and the fact $\pi$ is irrational is enough to force $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$.
The problem is $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ need not be real....

---

**Original answer**

This answer uses a little bit of transcendental number theory. It might be an overkill for this particular problem. However, it confirm whenever both $A$ and $\sin A$ are integer matrices, then $A^2 = 0$.

Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be eigenvalues of $A$.

When $A \in M(2,\mathbb{Z})$, its characteristic polynomial
$\chi_A(\lambda) \stackrel{def}{=}\det(\lambda I - A)$ will be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Since $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are roots of this polynomial, they will be algebraic numbers.

Notice $\sin A$ has $\sin(\lambda_1)$ and $\sin(\lambda_2)$ as its eigenvalues.
If $\sin A \in M(2,\mathbb{Z})$, then by same argument, $\sin\lambda_1$ and $\sin\lambda_2$ will be algebraic numbers.

By [Lindermann Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).
If $\alpha$ is any non-zero algebraic number, then $\sin\alpha$ will be transcendental. In order for all four numbers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \sin\lambda_1, \sin\lambda_2$ to be algebraic, we need $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$. This leaves us with two possibilities:

1. $A$ is diagonalizable and hence is equals to the zero matrix.
2. $A$ is similar to a Jordan block of order $2$ with zero diagonal.
   In this case, $A$ will be nilpotent and satisfies $A^2 = 0$.

In both cases, if both $A, \sin A \in M(2,\mathbb{Z})$, then $A^2 = 0$.

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed!

Comment: (+1) A similar problem appeared in problems section of [AMM June-July 2016](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.6.613) :)

Comment: @rpm interesting. apart from justifying $e^{\log(I-A)} = I-A$ for that $A$, argument here should continue to work...

Comment: Spurious downvotes. One thing for sure: far more people should come by and cast votes. Not too many take their civic duty serious these days, an attitude that will distort, in time, the reputation system Mathematics Stack Exchange is built upon. Too many questions and answers to wade through perhaps?